# SQL using listagg() and group by non duplicated values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
        ID TELNO
---------- --------------------
         1 0123456789
         1 0207983498
         2 0124339848
         2 09348374834
         2 02387694364
```

How can i query the above table to get output like this:

```
        ID TEL_LIST
---------- --------------------
         1 0123456789,0207983498
         2 0124339848,09348374834,09348374834
```

I know i can use the listagg() to concatenate the id's by grouping the columns. For example,

listagg(id',') within group (order by id) as idList

will return 1,2.

The TELNO column however cannot be grouped and the values are usually unique. How to do the concatenation on the second column where a group by is not possible?

Comment: :Can duplicate entry be possible or have you put a check on not putting duplicates value.Suppose `1 0123456789` is there and the same entry get inerted into table .Then this will cause problem .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEEXAMPLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aa277/2)**

```
SELECT 
ID, LISTAGG(TELNO, ', ') 
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TELNO) 
AS TEL_LIST
FROM   tbl
GROUP BY ID;
```

Result:

```
| ID |                             TEL_LIST |
---------------------------------------------
|  1 |               0123456789, 0207983498 |
|  2 | 0124339848, 02387694364, 09348374834 |
```

Answer (score 3):

I Don't know whether you have put a unique constraint on `ID,TELNO` or not .If not ,we need to filter the unique values from the Table first and then apply `LISTAGG` as shown below:

```
  SELECT ID,
       LISTAGG(TELNO, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID) AS TELNO
  FROM (
       SELECT UNIQUE
              ID,
              TELNO
         FROM tbl
       )
  GROUP BY ID;
```

**SQLFIDDLE:**[LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5a018/3)

If you look to the `execution place or the trace file` ,the cost will be the same on the same set of data, with query `JUSTIN` suggested in the above solution

Answer (score 2):

you can use wm_concat() function to perform the same.

```
 select id,wm_concat(telno) from my_table group by id;
```